Remove buttons from PowerPoint on Mac
in the top right corner of my PowerPoint, I have 4 buttons: Record, Comments, Present in Teams, Share. On the standard screen, this leads to some of the ribbons (Home, Insert, etc.) being hidden because of limited space.
Is there a way to individually remove those buttons?
Thank you


Perhaps this? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/manually-hide-teams-tool-bar-during-presentations/8060fa0e-bf1b-4246-b2f3-e71b035202cb
